# Vista update 800b0100

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer, updates, powershell

As I try to move from IE9 per-release to the regular IE9 I get the mostly useless error `800B0100`

`sfc` completed without error.

Using `firegenUL` I find the most common error to read

> HANDLER   FATAL: UH: 0x800b0100: EvaluateApplicability failed in
>   CCbs::EvaluateApplicability
>
> System update readiness tool gives me Checking Packages (f)   CBS MUM
>   Missing   0x00000002  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell-ISE-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~7.0.6002.18181.mum
>   (f)   CBS MUM
>   Missing   0x00000002  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell-WTR-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~7.0.6002.18181.mum

I tried to uninstall IE9 from command line as it doesn't show in installed updates.  Failed.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to install PowerShell, as the error message states it's not there?

Comment: I did try that - says it`s not applicable to my system (powershell 1 or 2).  I can`t see it in list of installed updates so I went into system32 and renamed WindowsPowerShell folder and that made no difference....

Comment: How hard did you try? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

Comment: This update does not apply to your system is the response.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Something else?

Comment: System Readiness Tool is your next step. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-the-System-Update-Readiness-Tool

Comment: Randolph I did that already...that's what gave me the CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002